# normal random variable concept

Tags: normal-distribution

Could someone please explain with example what *normal random variable* is (in normal distribution context)?

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It probably refers to a stochastic variable that has a Gaussian distribution.

Typical examples from real life are differences between two strongly correlated variables (for example the difference between the first and the second repeat of a weight measurement of the same object) or sums across large, homogenous populations (for example the sum of the weights of 1000 randomly selected objects from a fixed population)